# accessing the same static instance from two different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a singleton class `A`: the creation of the instance is done in the main thread `main()`, the class `thread` will launch the `mainThread()` that get the instance `_instance` of class `A`.

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    static void setInstance()
    {
        if (!_instance)
        {
            _instance = new A();
        }
    }
    static A* getInstance()
    {
        return _instance;
    }

    void bulk()
    {
        std::cout << "at A()" << std::endl;
    }
    static A* _instance;
};

A* A::_instance = 0;

class thread
{
public:
    thread() {}
    void threadMain()
    {
        // this is the thread main
        A::getInstance()->bulk();
    }
    std::thread member1Thread()
    {
        return std::thread([=] { threadMain(); });
    }
};

int main()
{

    A::setInstance();
    thread th;
    std::thread tw1 = th.member1Thread();
    A::getInstance()->bulk();
    delete A::_instance;

    return 0;
}
```

So `_instance` is a shared resource ? how I unblock this situation. I tried to go through a global `mutex`

```cpp
static A* getInstance()
{
    mutex.lock();
    return _instance;
}

void bulk()
{
    std::cout << "at A()" << std::endl;
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

does my code thread safe ?

Comment: Note that the `std::thread` created in your `thread` constructor is a local variable and will be destroyed as soon as the constructor completes.

Comment: @G.M. I've edited my question

Comment: The code as it stands is very fragile.  What if a single thread does `auto *s = A::getInstance(); s->bulk(); s->bulk();`?  In such a case you'll have mismatched calls to `lock` and `unlock`.  You need to think a bit more about the expected usage: do you want each member function to be thread-safe in its own right?  Do you want to be able to call multiple member functions as a single atomic transaction?

Comment: @G.M. I want to secure access to `_instance` because there is concurrent access between pricipal thread (main) and the secondary thread `tw1`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mostly thread safe. The tricks with the mutex work. However, you don't have guarantees that the new thread is finished by the time you delete the instance. You should join your thread before it to ensure it finished.

That said, this code wouldn't pass my code review. It's too unpredictable.

First of all, never call lock/unlock on mutexes. Use [std::unique_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) instead. That way you'll never forget to unlock as it will do it for you. As such, the locking should actually happen outside of the methods, which is easier to understand.

Secondly, this is one of the few places where [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) can make sense. You construct it once and pass the life time into the threads. However, you could as well put an instance on the stack, as you have control about the end of all threads.

Thirdly, [singletons are evil](https://wiki.c2.com/?SingletonsAreEvil).